# End-line characters from lines read from text file, using Python

Tags: python

When reading lines from a text file using python, the end-line character often needs to be truncated before processing the text, as in the following example:

```
f = open("myFile.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    line = line[:-1]
    # do something with line
```

Is there an elegant way or idiom for retrieving text lines without the end-line character?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The *idiomatic* way to do this in Python is to use **rstrip('\n')**:

```
for line in open('myfile.txt'):  # opened in text-mode; all EOLs are converted to '\n'
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    process(line)
```

Each of the other alternatives has a gotcha:

- **file('...').read().splitlines()** has to load the whole file in memory at once.
- **line = line[:-1]** will fail if the last line has no EOL.

Comment: HTTP and other protocols specify '\r\n' for line endings, so you should use line.rstrip('\r\n') for robustness.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I needed to open a text file and I was amazed to see that the \n - thing is even in Python as it is in Perl, C and so many other languages. I'll bookmark this and never forget it.

Answer (score 17):

Simple. Use **splitlines()**

```
L = open("myFile.txt", "r").read().splitlines();
for line in L: 
    process(line) # this 'line' will not have '\n' character at the end
```

Comment: But do note this loads the entire file into memory first, which may render it unsuitable for some situations.

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with your code?  I find it to be quite elegant and simple.  The only problem is that if the file doesn't end in a newline, the last line returned won't have a `'\n'` as the last character, and therefore doing `line = line[:-1]` would incorrectly strip off the last character of the line.

The most elegant way to solve this problem would be to define a generator which took the lines of the file and removed the last character from each line only if that character is a newline:

```
def strip_trailing_newlines(file):
    for line in file:
        if line[-1] == '\n':
            yield line[:-1]
        else:
            yield line

f = open("myFile.txt", "r")
for line in strip_trailing_newlines(f):
    # do something with line
```

Comment: Mac files using '\r', windows uses '\r\n', it starts to get chunky. Much better to use str.rstrip()

Comment: If the file is opened in text mode, the platform's native line endings are automatically converted to a single '\n' as they are read in.  And only _really old_ Mac OSs use plain '\r'.  You can't use rstrip() if you want to retain trailing spaces and tabs.

Comment: Good idea, with the generator. Would be handy in a reusable library. 
I would combine your solution with efonitis' solution (to save the if:else:). Without the reusable library at hand, I would prefer efotinis' solution (using line.rstrip('\n')).

Comment: +1; that's what I use. Could you please replace your `if`/`else` with `rstrip('\n')`?

Answer (score 5):

Long time ago, there was Dear, clean, old, BASIC code that could run on 16 kb core machines:
like that:

```
if (not open(1,"file.txt")) error "Could not open 'file.txt' for reading"
while(not eof(1)) 
  line input #1 a$
  print a$
wend
close
```

Now, to read a file line by line, with far better hardware and software (Python), we must reinvent the wheel:

```
def line_input (file):
    for line in file:
        if line[-1] == '\n':
            yield line[:-1]
        else:
            yield line

f = open("myFile.txt", "r")
for line_input(f):
    # do something with line
```

I am induced to think that something has gone the wrong way  somewhere...

Comment: While, considering that python is our best option for a entry level interpreted language, I agree on this comment, it could be convenient to notice that 16kb BASIC with a WHILE sentence were never common.

Answer (score 3):

What do you thing about this approach?

```
with open(filename) as data:
    datalines = (line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in data)
    for line in datalines:
        ...do something awesome...
```

Generator expression avoids loading whole file into memory and `with` ensures closing the file

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider using line.rstrip() to remove the whitespaces at the end of your line.

Comment: I use rstrip() as well, but you have to keep in mind it also takes out trailing spaces and tabs

Comment: As efotinis has shown, if you specify the chars argument, you can specfy what to strip. From the documentation: """rstrip([chars]) The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace."""