# Best method for reading newline delimited files and discarding the newlines?

Tags: python, file, readline

I am trying to determine the best way to handle getting rid of newlines when reading in newline delimited files in Python.

What I've come up with is the following code, include throwaway code to test.

```
import os

def getfile(filename,results):
   f = open(filename)
   filecontents = f.readlines()
   for line in filecontents:
     foo = line.strip('\n')
     results.append(foo)
   return results

blahblah = []

getfile('/tmp/foo',blahblah)

for x in blahblah:
    print x
```

Comment: what about using split("/n")?

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339537/end-line-characters-from-lines-read-from-text-file-using-python

Comment: I think it would be better to close the file as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Answer (score 207, accepted):

```
lines = open(filename).read().splitlines()
```

Comment: This answer does what I was going for, I'm sure I'll need to add some error checking and such, but for this specific need, it's great.  Thank you all for providing answers!

Comment: I like this but how do you close the file if you don't save off the file handle? Or is it automatically closed?

Comment: With CPython, the reference count for the file object will go to zero once it's no longer in use and the file will automatically be closed. For purely GC'd implementations like Jython and IronPython, the file may not be closed until the GC runs -- so this terse variation may not be optimal.

Comment: On Mac OS X 10.7.5 with 8GB RAM, I can read file of up to 2047MB (my definition: 1 MB = 1024 x 1024 bytes). 2048MB will throw MemoryError exception.

Comment: @WKPlus Excellent question -- the answer is "it depends" http://stackoverflow.com/a/15099341/994153  (CPython will close it since the reference count drops to zero, but other Python implementations might not close it, so best to make it explicit)

Comment: so it will be used as like this? `with open(file) as opened_file:
    lists = opened_file.read().splitlines()`

Answer (score 24):

Here's a generator that does what you requested. In this case, using rstrip is sufficient and slightly faster than strip.

```
lines = (line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(filename))
```

However, you'll most likely want to use this to get rid of trailing whitespaces too.

```
lines = (line.rstrip() for line in open(filename))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be [] around the RHS, not ()?

Comment: @andrewb Using () gives a generator expression, which doesn't use as much memory as using [] (a list comprehension.)

Answer (score 13):

What do you think about this approach?

```
with open(filename) as data:
    datalines = (line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in data)
    for line in datalines:
        ...do something awesome...
```

Generator expression avoids loading whole file into memory and `with` ensures closing the file

Comment: This is essentially the same as @TimoLinna's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/545188/355230) posted years beforehand...

Answer (score 8):

```
for line in file('/tmp/foo'):
    print line.strip('\n')
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use generator expressions:

```
blahblah = (l.rstrip() for l in open(filename))
for x in blahblah:
    print x
```

Also I want to advise you against reading whole file in memory -- looping over generators is much more efficient on big datasets.

Answer (score 3):

I use this

```
def cleaned( aFile ):
    for line in aFile:
        yield line.strip()
```

Then I can do things like this.

```
lines = list( cleaned( open("file","r") ) )
```

Or, I can extend cleaned with extra functions to, for example, drop blank lines or skip comment lines or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
f = open('test.txt')
l = [l for l in f.readlines() if l.strip()]
f.close()
print l
```

Comment: While Curt Hagenlocher's answer is technically better, this answer is a good starting point if you need to add other processing to each line.

Comment: Not sure if it was intended to filter blank lines, but this is more concise than `... if l.strip() is not ''`, which is what I need in my case.