# String Comparison Error

Tags: python

I've problem in the comparison line line == a[1] because it doesn't go to this loop. I tried testing the output and found that there is value 'a' in the file already. Below is my code.

```
a = "djsajdlasak"
f = open('users.txt','r+')
k = 0
for line in f:
    print line
    if line == a:
        k = 1
if k == 0:
    f.write(a + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Please explain exactly (1) what you're trying to do (2) what's the expected output (3) what's the current output or error messsage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for line in f` yields lines together with line terminators, so you need to strip them, see [to read line from file in python without getting "\n" appended at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280282/to-read-line-from-file-in-python-without-getting-n-appended-at-the-end)

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip out the newline/line terminator from the lines you are reading from the file. You can use `str.strip`, to achieve what you would would desire.

either change the line `for line in f:` `for line in(elem.strip() for elem in f):`
or add an extra line following your `for` statement

```
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    print line
    if line == a:
        k = 1
```