# unwanted \n after reading in lines

Tags: python, newline

I am trying to change directories via python, but the folder name is variable (chosen from a list):

```
f=open('folderlist.txt')
for line in f:

    pname = line

    os.chdir('./P574/%s' % (pname))
```

Which doesn't quite work because I get the error message:
"No such file or directory: './folders/folder_name2\n'"

The folder names I want are in a list called "folderlist.txt", but how do I stop python adding the '\n' at the end?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544921/best-method-for-reading-newline-delimited-files-in-python-and-discarding-the-new

Comment: It's not being added, it's in your text file. Use line.strip() to remove the whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [rstrip](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip). Change the line `pname = line` to

```
pname = line.rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: If he wants to remove only the newline you should use `line.rstrip('\n')`, otherwise also other whitespaces are removed(which may or may not be what he wants).