# Encoding in python

Tags: python

I have problem with comparing string from file with string I entered in the program, I should get that they are equal but no matter if i use decode('utf-8') I get that they are not equal. Here's the code:

```
final = open("info", 'r')
exported = open("final",'w')
lines = final.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if line == "Wykształcenie i praca": #error
    print "ok"
```

and how I save file that I try read:

```
comm_p = bs4.BeautifulSoup(comm)
comm_f.write(comm_p.prettify().encode('utf-8'))

for string in comm_p.strings:
      #print repr(string).encode('utf-8')
      save = string.encode('utf-8') #  there is how i save
      info.write(save)
      info.write("\n")        

info.close()
```

and at the top of file I have # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Any ideas?

Comment: add `print "%r %r" % (line, "Wykształcenie i praca")` right before the comparison line and tell us what it says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
import io

with io.open('info', encoding='utf-8') as final:
    lines = final.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if line.strip() == u"Wykształcenie i praca": #error
        print "ok"
```

You need to open the file with the right encoding, and since your string is not ascii, you should mark it as unicode.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the difference is in a '\n' character

[readlines](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) doesn't strip '\n' - see [Best method for reading newline delimited files in Python and discarding the newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544921/best-method-for-reading-newline-delimited-files-in-python-and-discarding-the-new)

In general it is not a good idea to put a Unicode string in your code, it would be a good idea to read it from a resource file

Comment: you're right, it's difficult to notice that small mistake when you think that encoding causes error :P

Answer (score 0):

First, you need some basic knowledge about encodings. [This is a good place to start](http://kunststube.net/encoding/). You don't have to read everything right now, but try to get as far as you can.

About your current problem:

You're reading a UTF-8 encoded file (probably), but you're reading it as an ASCII file. `open()` doesn't do any conversion for you.

So what you need to do (at least):

- use `codecs.open("info", "r", encoding="utf-8")` to read the file
- use Unicode strings for comparison: `if line.rstrip() == u"Wykształcenie i praca":`

Answer (score 0):

use unicode for string comparision

```
>>> s = u'Wykształcenie i praca'
>>> s == u'Wykształcenie i praca'
True
>>>
```

when it comes to string unicode is the smartest move :)