# python open & memory leaks

Tags: python, file-io

When is a file closed?

```
    # Read all data from input file
    mergeData = open( "myinput.txt","r" )
    allData = mergeData.read()
    mergeData.close()
```

Can I substitute this code?

```
allData = read.open( "myinput.txt","r" )
```

I was wondering when the file would be closed?  would be closed one the statement is run? or wait until the program exits.

Comment: I think you mean `allData = open('myinput.txt').read()`?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a guessing (beginner) python programmer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CPython closes a file object automatically when the object is deleted; it is deleted when it's reference count drops to zero (no more variables refer to it). So if you use `mergeData` in a function, as soon as the function is done, the local variables are cleaned up and the file is closed.

If you use `allData = open( "myinput.txt","r" ).read()` the reference count drops to 0 the moment `.read()` returns, and on CPython that means the file is closed there and then.

On other implementations such as Jython or IronPython, where object lifetime is managed differently, the moment an object is actually deleted could be much later.

The *best* way to use a file though, is as a context manager:

```
with open( "myinput.txt","r" ) as mergeData:
    allData = mergeData.read()
```

which calls `.close()` on `mergeData` *automatically*. See the [`file.open()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.close) and the documentation for the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

Comment: Wow, we both wrote like the exact same answer simultaneously.

Comment: @Iguananaut: it *is* an oft-asked question, there probably is a dupe somewhere.

Comment: through `with open .. as filehandle` filehandle automatically closes. However this will not work in Python 2.4 available in RHEL5.x and SLES10.x.

Comment: @kvivek: Python 2.4 is *really* ancient now. I am teaching best practices for the majority of Python installations instead. :-)

Comment: Is this also true for `asyncio.get_event_loop()` or is it more generally true when the relevant code exists inside of a function?

Comment: @SuperCodeBrah it is more generally true for local variables in a function, but the asyncio event loop returned by `asyncio.get_event_loop()` is special because it is managed by the asyncio module. The caller of `asyncio.get_event_loop()` is not the only reference to the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Yes you can.  There is no memory leak or anything of the sort.

The file handle will be closed soon after the `file` object returned by `open()` goes out scope and is garbage collected.

Though if you prefer you might wish to do something like:

```
with open('myinput.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

This will ensure that the file is closed as soon as you're done with it.