# cropping off characters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python and I have a `.txt` file containing numbers and I read them into an array in Python with the code below:

```
numberInput = []
with open('input.txt') as file:
     numberInput = file.readlines()
print numberInput
```

Unfortunately, the output looks like this:

```
['54044\r\n', '14108\r\n', '79294\r\n', '29649\r\n', '25260\r\n', '60660\r\n', '2995\r\n', '53777\r\n', '49689\r\n', '9083\r\n', '16122\r\n', '90436\r\n', '4615\r\n', '40660\r\n', '25675\r\n', '58943\r\n', '92904\r\n', '9900\r\n', '95588\r\n', '46120']
```

How do I crop off the `\r\n` characters attached to each number in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=splitlines#str.splitlines) instead of `readlines()`:

```
numberInput = []
with open('input.txt') as file:
     numberInput = file.read().splitlines()
print numberInput
```

This read the whole file and splits it by "universal newlines" so you get the same list without `\r\n`.

See this question:
[Best method for reading newline delimited files in Python and discarding the newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544921/best-method-for-reading-newline-delimited-files-in-python-and-discarding-the-new)

Comment: Please, one final question for you. First, thank you for the answer. it really worked. Before accepting your answer, I just need to ask if there is a way I could read in a text file containing 2000 random, unsorted numbers e.g 439,423, ...2000th number in python? I used the code above and it couldn't copy it but when I reduced the numbers to 100, it did. Any reason why it can't copy 2000 numbers?

Comment: Python doesn't limit this. You probably have some problem with your dataset. For example is every number separated by a newline in your file?

Answer (score 2):

The `\r\n` you're seeing at the end of the strings is the newline indicator (a carriage return character followed by a newline character). You can easily remove it using `str.strip`:

```
numberInput = [line.strip() for line in file]
```

This is a list comprehension that iterates over your file (one line at a time) and strips off any whitespace found at either end of the line.

If you're wanting to use the numbers from the file as integers though, you can actually avoid stripping the lines, since the `int` constructor will ignore any whitespace. Here's how it would look if you did the conversion directly:

```
numberInput = [int(line) for line in file]
```