# comparing strings: file and lists

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I'm doing a application that will the user enter a string, then all possible permutations and delete repeated.

The words of the permutations obtained should be compared line by line until a line equal to the permutation, and repeat the process with the remaining permutations.

The file contains this information: manila ana maria marta

or file: [espanol.dic](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1s5rg0szz2mzs2/espanol.dic)

Here attached a bit of code:

```
# coding=utf8
from __future__ import print_function
import os, re, itertools

new_dic_file = "espanol.dic"

def uniq(lst):
    # remove repeated
    key = dict.fromkeys(lst).keys()
    lst = list(key)
    return lst

def match(chars, num_chars):
    # Get the permutations of input string
    combs = itertools.permutations(chars, num_chars)
    result = []
    for combo in combs:
        result.append("".join(combo))

    # Iterate to Spanish dictionary and compare combinations of input string
    dic = open(new_dic_file)
    aux = dic.readlines()
    del dic
    aux = uniq(aux)

    for word in result:
        for word_dic in aux:
            print()
            print(word, word_dic, end="")
            print(type(word), type(word_dic), end="")
            if word == word_dic:
                print(word)
                print("########## Found! ##########")
```

I was printing the kind of "word" and "word_dic", and type 2 are str therefore should work, which does not ... 
I'm testing with this:
match("aan", 3)

and the result is this:

```
<type 'str'> <type 'str'>
ana marta
<type 'str'> <type 'str'>
ana ana
<type 'str'> <type 'str'>
ana manila
<type 'str'> <type 'str'>
naa maria
```

On what should be:

ana

#### Found!!

Any questions about what I do, please tell me ...

This is the complete code.
[test.py](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0fkgrk2uju5gf0/test.py)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `if word.strip() == word_dic.strip():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readlines` method leaves the LF characters on the strings. So the strings read from the file have an extra character in them. That's visible in the output; notice that the `type` lines fall below the strings, even though there is `end=""` on the `print` statements. The string "ana" with a newline is never equal to "ana".

To fix it, remove the `readlines()` statement and replace it with this:

```
aux = dic.read().splitlines()
```

See here for more on `readlines`: [Best method for reading newline delimited files in Python and discarding the newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544921/best-method-for-reading-newline-delimited-files-in-python-and-discarding-the-new)

Or you could leave the `readlines()` there but add this:

```
aux = [s.rstrip() for s in aux]
```

Comment: thank you very much!, you save me , this really works, I was never thinking about the new line, now your answer is now mark as accepted.