# Dealing with \n delimiter when reading flies in Python

Tags: python, file, text

Every time I read a text file using the following code in Python, each line (except the last) ends with the \n delimiter.

```
lines = open('the_file.txt').readlines()
```

Then, I'm forced to fix this using the following method:

```
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].replace('\n', '')
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this so that I don't have to use this hacky fix just to get rid of all of the \n instances?

Comment: This hacky fix doesn't even work.

Comment: Process the file line-by-line with `for line in file: process_line()`

Comment: The answer you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544921/best-method-for-reading-newline-delimited-files-in-python-and-discarding-the-new

Comment: You can't assign the value of a `for` loop counter due to garbage collection.

Comment: This also doesn't close the opened file until the scope is exited. It's better to use a `with` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
lines = open('the_file.txt').readlines()
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
```

Comment: `strip` removes excess whitespace and newines from strings.

Comment: `rstrip('\n')` would be more appropriate; with your code it will also strip any whitespace from the start of the line; which may not be desired.

Comment: Perhaps, but in the context of removing newlines, it appears that Ryan would also want to remove whitespace.