# How to split a txt file into two separate txt when there is a blank line separating?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text-editor

How can I split a single .txt file into two or more .txt files when a white line occours?

Here is a example of what my txt looks like:

```
a s d d d d s d f
f d e s s a d f s
a s d d d d s d f
f d e s s a d f s

dsdesd
dseesdse
```

I would like to know how to split this single text file into:

First txt file:

```
a s d d d d s d f
f d e s s a d f s
a s d d d d s d f
f d e s s a d f s
```

Second txt file:

```
dsdesd
dseesdse
```

Comment: Try writing some code, and if you get stuck, show the code to us.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split-file-after-x-lines-at-blank-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519139/split-file-after-x-lines-at-blank-line).

Comment: Split it on the double newline: `contents.split('\n\n')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the file will only have one blank line, you can [**`split`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the contents at the double newline character:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    contents = f.read()

output1, output2 = contents.split('\n\n')

with open('output1.txt', 'w') as o1:
    o1.write(output1)

with open('output2.txt', 'w') as o2:
    o2.write(output2)
```

If your file has more than one blank line this will fail as the split will return more than 2 parts and try to assign them to only two names, `output1` and `output2`. [**`split`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can be told to only split a maximum amount of times so it may be safer to say:

```
output1, output2 = contents.split('\n\n', 1)
```

If there are two or more blank lines, `output1` will be the contents up to the first blank line. `output2` will be everything after the first blank line, including any further blank lines.

Of course, this can fail if there are no blank lines.