# How to read a file without newlines?

Tags: python, line-breaks, readlines

In Python, calling e.g. `temp = open(filename,'r').readlines()` results in a list in which each element is a line from the file. However, these strings have a newline character at the end, which I don't want.

How can I get the data without the newlines?

Comment: Use strip: `[l.strip('\n\r') for l in temp]`. Or even `rstrip`. And since iteration here it can be `in open` instead of `in temp`.

Comment: I would be nice if in Python 3 there was a value to set open's `newline` argument to that chomped trailing newlines.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275018/how-can-i-remove-a-trailing-newline

Answer (score 955, accepted):

You can read the whole file and split lines using [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
temp = file.read().splitlines()
```

Or you can strip the newline by hand:

```
temp = [line[:-1] for line in file]
```

**Note:** this last solution only works if the file ends with a newline, otherwise the last line will lose a character.

This assumption is true in most cases (especially for files created by text editors, which often *do* add an ending newline anyway).

If you want to avoid this you can add a newline at the end of file:

```
with open(the_file, 'r+') as f:
    f.seek(-1, 2)  # go at the end of the file
    if f.read(1) != '\n':
        # add missing newline if not already present
        f.write('\n')
        f.flush()
        f.seek(0)
    lines = [line[:-1] for line in f]
```

Or a simpler alternative is to `strip` the newline instead:

```
[line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
```

Or even, although pretty unreadable:

```
[line[:-(line[-1] == '\n') or len(line)+1] for line in file]
```

Which exploits the fact that the return value of `or` isn't a boolean, but the object that was evaluated true or false.

---

The `readlines` method is actually equivalent to:

```
def readlines(self):
    lines = []
    for line in iter(self.readline, ''):
        lines.append(line)
    return lines

# or equivalently

def readlines(self):
    lines = []
    while True:
        line = self.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        lines.append(line)
    return lines
```

Since `readline()` keeps the newline also `readlines()` keeps it.

**Note:** for symmetry to `readlines()` the [`writelines()`](https://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines) method does *not* add ending newlines, so `f2.writelines(f.readlines())` produces an exact copy of `f` in `f2`.

Comment: Note that ``[line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]`` will remove more than one trailing ``\n``.

Comment: More simply, ``[line[:-(line[-1] == '\n') or len(line)+1] for line in file]`` could instead be ``[line[:-(line[-1] == '\n') or None] for line in file]``.

Comment: These solutions read the entire file into memory. Changing the square brackets of a list comprehension to parentheses makes a generator expression which lets you iterate over the file one line at a time:  `for line in (x.strip() for x in f):`

Comment: @velotron That's not really the point of the question/answer. Also: keep in mind that `with` closes the files when the block terminates, which means you cannot do `with open(...) as f: lines = (line for line in f)` and use `lines` outside the `with` because you'll get an I/O error. You can be lazy using a genexp, but you must consume it before closing the file.

Comment: @WesTurner. But there won't be more than one trailing newline. The extra newline will be part of the next empty line

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's great if you have some assurance that the data validates before parsing it.

Comment: A program that is supposed to read a file should never write to it. That's just bad practice.

Comment: @Bakuriu I'm new to this. I understand how 'temp = open(filename,'r').readlines()' works (opens filename 'filename' for reading). Could you explain how 'temp = file.read().splitlines()' relates to the original filename 'filename'?

Comment: @ndemarco `file = open(filename)`. A `filename` is a string of characters that represent a filesystem resource "on disk". `open` reads that strings and returns the actual resource, most of the times a simple file.

Comment: readline has to keep the newline or else how would you tell the difference between an empty line and the end of the file?

Comment: Note: You can use a [generator *expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to read text files incrementally line-by-line and remove the newlines from each one. For example: `with open(filename) as file:`, `for line in (line.rstrip() for line in file):`

Comment: The second option with iter is better when using 'rb' flag when opening the file. I had the case that a while loop and `if not line` did not work properly. `for line in iter(file.readline, b'')` worked for me then.

Answer (score 98):

```
temp = open(filename,'r').read().split('\n')
```

Comment: What would happen with `\r\n` newlines though? ;)

Comment: @WoLpH Yes, I didn't take the platform specific newlines into account. It'll give the wrong thing.

Comment: Python automatically handles universal newlines, thus `.split('\n')` will split correctly, independently of the newline convention.
It would matter if you read the file in binary mode.In that case `splitlines()` handles universal newlines while `split('\n')` doesn't.

Comment: And there's always `os.linesep` :)

Comment: @askewchan: That's true, but would it help? If the file you're reading contains the "wrong" line endings for your OS, `os.linesep` would be unhelpful. And if Bakuriu is right (I assume he is) that Python does the right thing magically (in text mode), then `os.linesep` is unnecessary. Still it does feel cleaner that `\n`.

Comment: @LarsH, it would help in some circumstances, on my system `\r\n` line endings are _not_ converted to `\n`, whether read as text or binary, so `os.linesep` would work where `\n` does not. But `splitlines` is clearly the better choice, in the case you mention where the file does not match the os. Really I mostly mentioned it in case people looking at this discussion were unaware of its existence.

Comment: @askewchan Maybe you're using an out of date version of Python. I believe that as of Python 3, universal newlines are enabled by default i.e. `\r\n` would be converted for text files even when you are running on Linux.

Comment: `open()` [defaults to read mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). You don't have to pass `'r'`.

Answer (score 37):

Reading file one row at the time. Removing unwanted chars from end of the string with [`str.rstrip(chars)`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fileobj:
    for row in fileobj:
        print(row.rstrip('\n'))
```

See also `str.strip([chars])` and `str.lstrip([chars])`.

Comment: The read mode is [the default mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). You don't have to pass the `'r'` explicitly.

Answer (score 26):

I think this is the best option.

```
temp = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
```

Comment: This solution also removes leading and trailing spaces, which is not intended.

Comment: The comprehension is really nice, though. At least with Python 3, one can use `temp = [line.rstrip() for line in file.readlines()]` to get what @Roland_Illig notes is intended.

Comment: If you're going to iterate over all the lines, why do not so lazily? With `.readlines()`, you're effectively iterating over the entire file twice.

Comment: To be clear, the `readlines()` call is redundant, so this could be just `temp = [line.strip() for line in file]`.

Answer (score 14):

```
temp = open(filename,'r').read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Are you sure this closes the file ? I think it does not, so it is not really a one-liner...

Comment: `with` is recommended to use for open-commands. For example: `with open(file) as f: temp = f.read().splitlines()`

Answer (score 12):

My preferred one-liner -- if you don't count `from pathlib import Path` :)

```py
lines = Path(filename).read_text().splitlines()
```

This it auto-closes the file, no need for `with open()...`

Added in Python 3.5.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
u=open("url.txt","r")  
url=u.read().replace('\n','')  
print(url)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: I don't see why anyone should use this over some of the alternative solutions.

Comment: This only works, if the file contains exactly one line. If the file contains many lines, it removes the information, where each line ended.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file as a list easily using a list comprehension

```
with open("foo.txt", 'r') as f:
    lst = [row.rstrip('\n') for row in f]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of trailing end-of-line (`/n`) characters and of empty list values (`''`), try:

```
f = open(path_sample, "r")
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines() if line.strip() != '']
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **pathlib.Path.read_text()**, this opens the file in text mode, reads it and closes the file.

```
from pathlib import Path

temp = Path(filename).read_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use `readline()`, you can strip the newline as you read each line.  It seems both intuitive and seems to fit the python style (at least to me).

```
file = open("foo", "r")
aLineOfText = file.readLine().strip('\n')
```

Put this in a loop if you have to read multiple lines.  This is a good work-around if the file is too big to be read into memory in one swoop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward solution is calling the `splitlines()` function on the file object.

Here's a modification of your code:

```py
temp = open(filename,'r').read().splitlines()
```

This will return a list of all the lines in the file as a string, with each line breaking at `\n`. Essentially, it will eliminate all line breaks.

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines

Answer (score -2):

```
my_file = open("first_file.txt", "r")
for line in my_file.readlines():
    if line[-1:] == "\n":
        print(line[:-1])
    else:
        print(line)
my_file.close()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation so that it will be useful to others.

Comment: You should use a context manager to handle the file object, and iterate over the file directly. By using `.readlines()` like this, you're effectively iterating over the entire file twice.

Answer (score -2):

This script here will take lines from **file** and save every line without newline with ***,0*** at the end in **file2**.

```
file = open("temp.txt", "+r")
file2 = open("res.txt", "+w")
for line in file:
    file2.writelines(f"{line.splitlines()[0]},0\n")
file2.close()
```

if you looked at ***line***, this value is ***data\n***, so we put `splitlines()`

to make it as an *array* and ***[0]*** to choose the only word ***data***

Answer (score -3):

```python
import csv

with open(filename) as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in csvreader:
         print(line[0])
```

Comment: But what if the line has a comma in it?

Comment: Strictly not a solution for the question, because of the comma glitch. But i gave it a upvote, as it a nice trix that i just used in a similar case, where i did `.split(',')` on all lines anyway