# Python: how to make it not change line

Tags: python, string, file

There's a file with various names on it, each name as /n at the end of it so when I open the file in python it prints each name in a different line

The problem is I have to print 2 names on each line, I'v tried everything but I still can't because of the "/n" at the end of every name, making it change line

for example :

```
f=open('nomes.txt','r')
lines=f.readlines()

for line in lines:

   print line,
```

prints each name on different line even with the ',' at the end of the print.

help?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space

Answer (score 2):

`readlines()` returns end of the lines in each token.
You need either to remove it or to use split lines:

```
f=open('nomes.txt','r')
lines = f.read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
   print line,
```

Then you can use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and print a \n when index is mod 2.
Example:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(lines):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
      print val,  #print without \n
    else
      print val   #print with \n
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines)