# Using .read() adds extra nonetype character

Tags: python, string, loops

```
input = open("ex3.txt")
DNA = input.read()
DNA2 = "AAAACCCGGT"
print "string=", DNA,"len=", len(DNA)
print "strin2=",DNA2,"len=",len(DNA2)
```

returns

```
>string= AAAACCCGGT
>len= 11
>strin2= AAAACCCGGT len= 10
```

As you can see, the two strings which appear identical have different lengths because when I load the input using input.read() the string ends in Nonetype (edit: actually ends in '\n')

Is there a way to load string input from a textfile without it ending in Nonetype?  Or should I just load as is and splice the input like DNA[:-1] assuming .read() will always have Nonetype as the final value?

Thanks for any tips :-D

Edit:  I supposed the reason I was confused about Nonetype is because of the error message:
"TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects"  Anyways, calling .rstrip worked great thanks again everyone

Comment: `\n` means **newline**, not `None`.

Comment: how do you know that `DNA` ends in a Nonetype?  Are you sure it's not just that your file ends in `\n`?

Comment: I won't close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines because there is an important misunderstanding in this post about what `\n` *is*, but it's worth at least reading that link.

Comment: Try `print repr(DNA), repr(DNA2)` to see what's actually in each of them. There is no such thing as `Nonetype` character.

Comment: OK, thanks everyone.  print repr(DNA) shoes that my string did in fact end in a newline which was showing up as a blank char with type ='str'.  I've added .rstrip() as the proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.read` on files in text mode will always `\n` **iff** there is a return character. This means that `DNA[:-1]`  can break if the line does not have another line after it.

One way to do what you want is `DNA.rstrip()`. This removes whitespace to the right of the string.

Also, you probably want `.readline` if you know you want to read a line. `read` reads the whole file, which may be several lines.