# Removing \n from file being read by while loop

Tags: python

This is my code below and it outputs mostly what I want, but it contains \n after each number and I do not know how to get rid of it...any help? Thanks!

```
def main():
    scores = []
    scores_file = open('scores.txt', 'r')
    line_list = list(scores_file.readlines())
    print(line_list)
    i = 0
    while i < len(line_list):
        scores.append(line_list[i])
        i += 1


main()
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to keep the while loop (which you shouldn't)

```
def main():
    scores = []
    scores_file = open('scores.txt', 'r')
    line_list = scores_file.readlines()
    scores_file.close()
    i = 0

    while i < len(line_list):
        scores.append(int(line_list[i].strip()))
        i += 1
    print(scores)

main()
```

If you find the list comprehension a little hard to follow it can be broken down to an actual loop like this.

```
def main():
    scores = []
    with open('scores.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            scores.append(int(line.strip()))
    print(scores)
```

You avoid having to have the list index variable `i` and all the ugliness and possibility for mistakes that go with it.

Comment: I know the while loop is stupid, its a question that needed to be answered like that.

Comment: `readlines()` already returns a `list` - no need to cast with `list()`.

Comment: ok fine i just copied the OP's code. It still gives the right output

Comment: @John, if the assignment has an oddball requirement like "you must use a while loop," please clearly state it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('scores.txt', 'r') as f:
    scores = [int(line.strip()) for line in f]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Not working for me, must be doing something wrong. I would place that after the opening of the scores.txt file in main right?

Comment: This does open the file, remove the other open. It replaces all the code in your `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('scores.txt') as f:
    scores = f.read().splitlines()
```