# Reading characters from a file into a list causing problems

Tags: python, list, file, tkinter

I have some code which chooses a random word from a list of words and displays it on a label. The user then has to retype this word correctly to score a point.
I decided to use a text file to store the words and read it into a list in the program but this is causing problems.

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *

import random

with open("WORDS_FILE.txt") as f:
    WORDS = list(f.readlines())

word_count = 0

def shuffle():
    global word
    go_btn.pack_forget()

    while word_count < 4:        
        word = random.choice(WORDS)        
        label.config(text=str(word))    
        return

def check(event):
    global word, word_count

    if entry.get().lower() == word.lower():
        update_right()

    elif entry.get().lower() != word.lower():
        update_wrong()

    shuffle()
    entry.delete(0, END)

def update_right():
    global word, word_count

    word_count += 1
    WORDS.remove(word)    
    wrong_label.config(text="")

def update_wrong():
    global word, word_count
    wrong_label.config(text="WRONG!", fg='red')

root = Tk()          
label = Label(root, font=("Helvetica", 60))
wrong_label = Label(root, text="", font =("Helvetica, 14"))                                      

go_btn = Button(root, text="GO!", command=shuffle)
entry = Entry(root)

root.bind("<Return>", check)

label.pack()
wrong_label.pack()
go_btn.pack()
entry.pack()

entry.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

My problem is that even if I retype the word correctly, it is still always wrong. I have checked the text file and there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with. Text file is as follows:

```
Games
Development
Keyboard
Speed
Typer
Anything
Syndicate
Victory
```

Comment: Probably you have "end of line" characters when reading the word in the file.

Comment: `readlines` doesn't remove `\n`

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was the comparisons in the `if-statements` that were causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error comes from here:

```
with open("WORDS_FILE.txt") as f:
    WORDS = list(f.readlines()) #Carriage return is given in each line.
```

In this part, you read each line of the file and create a list of it, using `list` constructor. However, each line has a carriage return at the end, when reading from a file. So basically, you want to remove the carriage return by applying `.strip('\n')` on each string of your list. This could be done naively like this:

**Bad way of doing it:**

```
with open("WORDS_FILE.txt") as f:
    WORDS = list(f.readlines()) #Carriage return is given in each line.
for i in range(len(WORDS)): # Iterate over list indexes
    WORDS[i] = WORDS[i].strip('\n') # In place string replacement.
```

While that does the trick, it does not seem right to iterate over your word list twice (once when reading the file in `f.readlines()`, and once after when stripping `'\n'`). There is two solutions for avoiding this:

**Solution 1: Explicit file reading iteration:**

```
WORDS = []
with open("WORDS_FILE.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        WORDS.append(line.strip('\n'))
```

**Solution 2: apply the `.strip('\n')` function on each item generated by `.readlines()`**, using the function `map` and a *lambda-expression*:

```
with open("WORDS_FILE.txt") as f:
    WORDS = list(map(lambda s: s.strip('\n'), f.readlines()))
```

Comment: Thanks I tried using `strip()` on it's own but it wouldn't work, didn't realise I was missing something

Comment: @DwainDwarf I bet your question would be more helpful if you explained how the lambda is working and why it is a better option then just a list comprehension.  You have a lot of cool stuff in there but I think a novice would struggle to understand what is going on

Comment: @PyNExbie : I've editted much of my answer