# Importing file lines into a set without EOL characters and without post-processing

Tags: python

i've got a file that basically is a list, every entry is separated by carraige return.
I'm trying to load this lines into a set() with this code:

```
with open('file','r') as f:
  entries = set()
  for row in f:
    entries.add(row)
```

The file looks like this:

```
entry1
entry2
entry3
```

In the end, the set looks like this if i print it:

```
set(['entry1\r\n', 'entry2\r\n'...])
```

I've got to do work with the set and i can't do searches and stuff with this EOL chars.

Comment: `entries.add(row.rstrip())`

Comment: put it on responses so i can  mark green

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.rstrip()` to strip the carriage return

```
with open('file','r') as f:
  entries = set()
  for row in f:
    entries.add(row.rstrip())
```

## Links

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rstrip.htm