# Removing '\n', [, and ] in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a GUI that will generate a random names for taverns for some tabletop gameplay. I have .txt docs that have something like this.

```
Red
Green
Yellow
Resting
Young
```

And

```
King
Dragon
Horse
Salmon
```

I'm reading and randomly joining them together using the following

```
x = 1
tavern1 = open('tavnames1.txt', 'r')
name1 = tavern1.readlines()
tav1 = random.sample(name1, int(x))
tav1 = str(tav1)
tav1 =tav1.strip()
tav1 =tav1.replace('\n', '')


tavern2 = open('tavnames2.txt', 'r')
name2 = tavern2.readlines()
tav2 = random.sample(name2, int(x))
tav2 = str(tav2)


TavernName = 'The' + tav1 + tav2


print(TavernName)
```

The output I get will look something like

```
The['Young\n']['Salmon\n']
```

I've tried using .replace() and .strip() on the string but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Take the first value from `tav1` and `tav2`, by doing `tav1[0].strip()`. The `.strip()` takes care of the `\n`.

Comment: Sorry I'm not overly fluent in python, can you elaborate a bit more please.

Comment: `sample()` always return list - even if it has one element - so `tav1` and `tav2` are lists and you use `str()` to convert it to text. Use `tav1 = tav1[0]` or `random.choice(name1)` to get only one element.

Answer (score 3):

`sample()` always returns list - even if there is one element. And you use `str()` to convert list into string so Python adds `[ ]`, and `strip()` doesn't work because `\n` is not at the end of string.

But you can use `random.choice()` which returns only one element - so you don't have to convert to string and you don't get `[ ]`. And then you can use `strip()` to remove `\n`

```
tavern1 = open('tavnames1.txt')
name1 = tavern1.readlines()
tav1 = random.choice(name1).strip()

tavern2 = open('tavnames2.txt')
name2 = tavern2.readlines()
tav2 = random.choice(name2).strip()

tavern_name = 'The {} {}'.format(tav1, tav2)

print(tavern_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

A way to get rid of the newlines is to read the whole file and use `splitlines()`: (see [Reading a file without newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines))

```
tavern1 = open('tavnames1.txt', 'r')
name1 = tavern1.read().splitlines()
```

To pick a random item of the list `name1` you can use `tav1 = random.choice(name1)` (see https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.choice).

Answer (score 0):

Take the first value from `tav1` and `tav2`, by doing `tav1[0].strip()`. The `.strip()` takes care of the `\n`.

By taking a `random.sample`, you get a list of values. Because you take just one sample, you get a list with just one item in it, in your example "Young". But, it is in a list, so it is more like `["Young"]`. To access only `"Young"`, take the first (and only) item from the list, by saying `tav1[0]`.

Comment: You could also use `random.choice(your_list)` to get 1 single random item from the list

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. Thanks for that! This worked a treat