# set function with file- python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file with given below content

```
Credit

Debit

21/12/2017

09:10:00
```

Written python code to convert text into set and discard \n.

```
with open('text_file_name', 'r') as file1:
    same = set(file1)
    print (same)
    print (same.discard('\n'))
```

for first print statement  print (same). I get correct result:

```
{'Credit\n','Debit\n','21/12/2017\n','09:10:00\n'}
```

But for second print statement `print (same.discard('\n'))` . I am getting result as
`None`.

Can anybody help me to figure out why I am getting None. I am using `same.discard('\n')` to discard `\n` in the set.

Note:
I am trying to understand the discard function with respect to set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a file without newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines)

Comment: `same = set(line.rstrip() for line in file1)`

Answer (score 1):

The `discard` method will only remove an element from the set, since your set doesn't contain just `\n` it can't discard it. What you are looking for is a map that strips the `\n` from each element like so:

```
set(map(lambda x: x.rstrip('\n'), same))
```

which will return `{'Credit', 'Debit', '09:10:00', '21/12/2017'}` as the set. This sample works by using the `map` builtin which applies it's first argument to each element in the set. The first argument in our `map` usage is `lambda x: x.rstrip('\n')` which is simply going to remove any occurrences of `\n` on the right-hand side of each string.

Comment: I think this would be the most memory & time efficient answer because the builtin map method is implemented in C.

Answer (score 0):

`discard` removes the given element from the `set` only if it presents in it.
In addition, the function doesn't return any value as it changes the `set` it was ran from.

```
with open('text_file_name', 'r') as file1:
    same = set(file1)
    print (same)
    same = {elem[:len(elem) - 1] for elem in same if elem.endswith('\n')}
    print (same)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 4 elements in the `set`, and none of them are newline.

It would be more usual to use a `list` in this case, as that preserves order while a set is not guaranteed to preserve order, plus it discards duplicate lines. Perhaps you have your reasons.

You seem to be looking for [rstrip('\n')](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip). Consider processing the file in this way:

```
    s = {}
    with open('text_file_name') as file1:
        for line in file1:
            s.add(line.rstrip('\n'))
    s.discard('Credit')
    print(s) # This displays 3 elements, without trailing newlines.
```

Comment: Even if there WAS a newline as an element of the set, you would still get `None` as the result from the `.discard()` method.  Its job is to remove an element from an existing set, it doesn't need to return anything since you already have the set.

Comment: It appeared to me the OP was confused about how far into the collection `discard` would reach, so I tried to answer the real question ("how do I strip newlines?") rather than the one that literally appeared in the posting. I was trying to be helpful.