# How to eliminate new line character from text file when opened in python?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

I am trying to take words from stopwords.txt file and append them as string in python list.

stopwords.txt

```
  a
  about
  above
  after
  again
  against
  all
  am
  an
  and
  any
  are
  aren't
  as
  at
  be
  because
  been
  before
  being
```

My Code :

```
    stopword = open("stopwords.txt", "r")
    stopwords = []
    for word in stopword:
        stopwords.append(word)
```

List stopwords output:

```
    ['a\n',
     'about\n',
     'above\n',
     'after\n',
     'again\n',
     'against\n',
     'all\n',
     'am\n',
     'an\n',
     'and\n',
     'any\n',
     'are\n',
     "aren't\n",
     'as\n',
     'at\n',
     'be\n',
     'because\n',
     'been\n',
     'before\n',
     'being\n']
```

Desired Output :

```
    ['a',
     'about',
     'above',
     'after',
     'again',
     'against',
     'all',
     'am',
     'an',
     'and',
     'any',
     'are',
     "aren't",
     'as',
     'at',
     'be',
     'because',
     'been',
     'before',
     'being']
```

Is there any method to transpose stopword so that it eliminate '\n' character or any method at all to reach the desire output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a file without newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
stopwords.append(word)
```

do

```
stopwords.append(word.strip())
```

The `string.strip()` method strips whitespace of any kind (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) from the start and end of the string. You can give an argument to the function in order to strip a specific string or set of characters, or use `lstrip()` or `rstrip()` to only strip the front or back of the string, but for this case just `strip()` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.strip()` method. It removes all occurrences of the character passed as an argument from a string:

```
stopword = open("stopwords.txt", "r")
stopwords = []
for word in stopword:
    stopwords.append(word.strip("\n"))
```