# Are you able to make a dictionary like this? (Using external .txt files)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is there an easier way of creating a dictionary on Python from a .txt file than this:

```
for y in open('bones.txt'):
    bones={','.join(y:'0')}
```

where `bones.txt` contains:

```
Ankylosaurus
Pachycephalosaurus
Ankylosaurus
Tyrannosaurus Rex
Ankylosaurus
Struthiomimus
Struthiomimus
```

Comment: `','.join(y:'0')` gives me a `SyntaxError` - what exactly is this line supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

```
with open("bones.txt") as f:
    my_dict = dict.fromkeys(f, '0')
```

Thanks for the suggustions and I get this answer above.

1. use `dict` instead of `{}`
2. Don't use `readlines`. The `file iterator` works

to clean out **line breaks**, maybe we can use `os.linesep`

```
import os
with open("bones.txt") as f:
    my_dict = dict.fromkeys(map(lambda x: x.replace(os.linesep, ""), f), '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension.

```
with open('bones.txt') as f:
    bones = { line: 0 for line in f.read().splitlines() }
```

[str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) does not include the newline character to the lines, so we don't have to strip it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist not in my case. Can it be due to Python version/OS? I'm using Python 3.5 on Ubuntu

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, I've tried, I get something like this `['q\n', 'w\n', 'e\n', 'r\n', 't\n', 'y\n', '\n']` as the output

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think it is common https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines
I came to a cleaner solution with `splitlines()`

Comment: @MadPhysicist the file iterator doesn't strip anything, neither in python 2.7x nor in 3.6.5, so I doubt it does in 3.5.x.

Answer (score 0):

This method can also be modified to include values for keys without making it too complicated:

```
bones = {}
for y in open('bones.txt'):
   bones[y.strip('\n')] = '0'
```

Comment: Why convert something that is already a string into a string?

Comment: Why not use a with block when you really should?

Comment: I wanted to do it keeping Op's approach. and newline character is there to strip. for your point 1, I made the edit. Thanks.

Comment: OP came here to learn. It's up to you to instruct him not to make the mistakes he's making.

Comment: Ideally you could include the `with`-based solution with a little comment after yours to your answer

Comment: @SashaTsukanov The solution including `with` based solution provided by Henry yuan and Mad Physicist is more elegant. Personally I wanted to present a solution with the basic operations which gives the solution keeping Op's way of thought.

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you please tell me what have you edited in my solution so I can keep that in mind for the future?

Comment: When a vote sits for too long, you can't change it unless an edit is made to the post. I wanted to remove my downvote, so I made an edit that I considered to be harmless. If you want me to change the colon back to a period, I'd be more than happy to do it.

Comment: Wishing had the privilege to upvote your comment. and no, the colon is harmless. cheers.