# Python when splitting line in file it leaves newline in the end

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to make a simple question/answer program, where the questions are written in a normal text file like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug5pK.png)

Problem is when i split the code (at the #) it also leaves the newline, meaning anyone using the program would have to add the newline to the answer. Any way to remove that newline so only the answer is required?

Code:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
p = 0
for line in file:
    list = line.split("#")
    answer = input(list[0])
    if answer == list[1]:
        p = p + 1
print("points:",p)
```

Comment: You are opening `file1` but reading the built-in function name `file`. Please make sure the posted code is *exactly* the code you are asking about.

Comment: But sure; reading a line preserves the trarling newline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a file without newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines)

Comment: Don't name list as `list` because it shadows the built-in.

Comment: @tripleee Python 3.6, `>>> file` raises `... NameError: name 'file' is not defined`

Comment: OTOH the OP should avoid naming their lists `list` because that name shadows a Python built in.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize it was removed! Good riddance.

Answer (score 0):

Strip all the whitespace from the right side of your input:

```
list[1] = list[1].rstrip()
```

Or just the newlines:

```
list[1] = list[1].rstrip('\n')
```

Using `list` as a variable name is a bad idea because it shadows the built-in class name. You can use argument unpacking to avoid the issue entirely and make your code more legible:

```
prompt, expected = line.split('#')
expected = expected.rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rstrip()`, which, without arguments, will default to stripping any whitespace character. So just modify the conditional slightly, like this.

```
if answer == list[1].rstrip():
```