# unable to understand lambda map function

Tags: python

Seeking guidance to understand a lambda-map function. In the below, I see that the file "feedback" is read line by line and stored in a list "feedback". I'm unable to get my head around the variable x. I don't see the variable "x" declared anywhere. Can someone help me understand the statement?Thanks in advance

```
f = open('feedback.txt','r') 
feedback = list(map(lambda x:x[:-1],f.readlines())
f.close()
```

Comment: `lambda x:` declares the variable.

Comment: That's not good code to be learning from, it should be something like `with open('feedback.txt') as f: feedback = [line.rstrip() for line in f]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree. For a noob in Python I found it difficult to get my head around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map function will execute the given function for every element in the list.

In your code the map function will get `lambda x:x[:-1]`.
You can read that like: for every x in f.readlines() return everything except the last element of x.

So `x` will be every line the file. `lambda x:` you could see as `def thing(x):`.

Comment: Thanks @bob for the explanation. Now I understand :)

Answer (score 2):

I replaced lambda with a standard func:

```
def read_last(x):  #x means a line
  return x[:-1]

f = open('feedback.txt','r') 
feedback = list(map(read_last, f.readlines())
f.close()
```

Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

lambda function is a simple anonymous function that takes  any number of arguments, but has only one expression.

```
lambda arguments : expression
```

It is anonymous because we have not assigned it to an object, and thus it has no name.

example f and g are somewhat same:

```
def f(x):
    # take a string and return all but last value
    return x[:-1]

g = lambda x: x[:-1]
```

so:

```
f('hello') == g('hello') #True ->'hell'
```

But g is not how we would use lambda. The whole aim is to avoid assigning ;)

Now map takes in a function and applies it to an iteratable:it returns a generator  in Python 3+ and thus a list is used to case that generator to a list

```
data = ['we are 101','you are 102','they are 103']

print(list(map(lambda x:x[:-1],data)))

#->['we are 10','you are 10','they are 10']
```

In principle, same as passing a function:

```
data = ['we are 101','you are 102','they are 103']

print(list(map(f,data)))
```

but often faster and awesome. I love lambdas

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, while explaining lambda is solved here, it is not the implementation of choice for your particular example. Suggestion:

```
f = open('feedback.txt', 'r')
feedback = f.read().splitlines()
f.close()
```

[See also 'Reading a file without newlines'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines)