# Reading line from file, adding String + newline to each line and writing to target file

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7
and trying to read from pipe-delimited Src file, adding string to each line
and writing the string to another file.

```
def createInfoTypeFile(srcDir, targetFile, startWith):
  for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(srcDir):
      for file in files:
          fpath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
          if (fpath.endswith('.SAP')):
              f = open(fpath, 'r')
              lines = f.readlines()
              for line in lines:
                  if line.startswith(startWith):
                      line1 = line + "|key|false\n"
                      targetFile.write(line1)
```

I call the above code, passing it the src, target files and a starting string

The string gets appended to the line, but after a new line

```
a|b|
|key|false
```

'key|false|' - is what i'm adding to each Line read, but after newline 
I want |key|false added to the original line w/o newline

i.e.

```
a|b|key|false
```

Comment: I think `open(filename,'r').read().split('\n')` can help you sort the issue out - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330540/4092588) for further info

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a file without newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-a-file-without-newlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line1 = line.rstrip() + "|key|false\n"
```

Strip out the extra newline from the original before appending.