# Python adding new line when printing indexes from tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I'm trying to print two separate indexes from two separate tuples on the same line. but when I print using f-strings it puts the second index I print on a new line.

Can't seem to figure it out no matter what I try it always prints on a new line the surname.

```
surnames = tuple(open("Surnames.txt", "r"))
first_names_male = tuple(open("Male_names.txt", "r"))
first_names_female = tuple(open("Female_names.txt", "r"))

print(f"{first_names_male[0]} {surnames[0]}")
```

Should print out "David Smith" all on one line

Instead, it shows David on the first line then on the next line has a space and then Smith

Comment: That is a really strange use of `open()`. Normally you would read the file contents into a list first.

Comment: The "error" probably happens because each line from the file ends in a newline char. If you don't want that, try reading the first line and use `.strip()` on that line

Comment: try `print(f"{first_names_male[0].strip()} {surnames[0].strip()}")`

Comment: better to explicitly store the file handle so it can be closed (or use `with`)

Comment: Perfect, yes that works! Is there an easier way to read the file then? rather than using the tuple as i have?

Comment: please read cpython official doc: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 1):

You could use code like this to remove the new lines from the end of each line in the file and to explicitly close the files:

```
with open("Surnames.txt", "r") as f:
    surnames = f.read().splitlines()
with open("Male_names.txt", "r") as f:
    first_names_male = f.read().splitlines()
with open("Female_names.txt", "r") as f:
    first_names_female = f.read().splitlines()

print(f"{first_names_male[0]} {surnames[0]}")
```

Or something like this if you prefer:

```
with open("Surnames.txt", "r") as f:
    surnames = map(str.rstrip, f)
    # or
    surnames = [r.rstrip('\n') for r in f]
```

For more options, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330535/3830997

Comment: I think there is also `.readlines()` instead of `.read()` that could be used

Comment: Yeah, but `f.readlines()` keeps the newlines at the end of each line, so it's pretty much equivalent to `list(f)`. Either way, you have to strip off the newlines before you can work with the rows.

Comment: Interesting distinction; I did not notice that. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better handling of the files, because it also closes the files and removes newlines from the end of each line.

```
def func(filename):
    line_list = []

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) > 0:
                line_list.append(line)

    return line_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    surnames_list = func('Surnames.txt')
    male_names_list = func('Male_names.txt')
    female_names_list = func('Female_names.txt')

    print(f"{male_names_list[0]} {female_names_list[0]}")
```

Does this give you the desired result?

Comment: I seem to get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @lammyalex sorry, forgot to include `return` in the function