# Getting rid of \n (newline) in Python dictionary

Tags: python

I am reading a file and turning it into a dictionary but cannot get rid of the \n in the dictionary key.

Here is my code:

```
file = open('textfile.txt')

dct = {line.split(":")[0]:line.split(":")[1] for line in file}

print(dct)
```

And here is the output:

> {'John': 'e6868d7b1cb85386cd8bcca41a87ae22c124421caff73d5934982bf5324ef3f6\n', 'Mary': 'cdc7283def7099d7b1a1479b14bb0b4f4c1dafa5e0d7ca2f971e103c5ca2cf91\n', 'Bob': '50bdd8da1bf88ef117720f9be735459bc61403d9c2d59de9365e47636ed7ecf8\n', 'Jane': '11a4a60b518bf24989d481468076e5d5982884626aed9faeb35b8576fcd223e1\n', 'Peter': 'ef794d0f3a4eb6bf12e7b5d1c554ce14e806096e754d118c0a53b7b3d73b9867\n', 'Julia': '7bd9ca7a756115eabdff2ab281ee9d8c22f44b51d97a6801169d65d90ff16327\n', 'Mike': '7ea29f746dc7abe2893bb4279c06aa1e4443c90c4ea2da75557b548d4ecf6694\n', 'Alice': '65791165c0545089fdd23860a47cb594e81aecf30ceb4013944e2eb20b16a959\n', 'Zach': '69aeb1c2851e1a68538654740c7fccccb8d91c2ee96f5281bfba22443045105c\n', 'Vicky': 'bf8ee9479549dde9721ae599d133574ff8230b3cee81baa4f954880af571aa53\n'}

Comment: `dct = {line.split(":")[0]:line.split(":")[1].strip() for line in file}
`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading file without newlines in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/reading-file-without-newlines-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Try by stripping `'\n'` from the right side when generating the dictionary:

```
{line.split(":")[0]:line.split(":")[1].rstrip('\n') for line in file}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can insert another generator to avoid splitting twice. It would also be nice to open the file in a context, so that it gets autoclosed.

```
with open('textfile.txt') as file:
    dct = { k: v for k, v, *_ in (line.rstrip().split(':') for line in file) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim the string,

```
dct = {line.split(":")[0]:line.split(":")[1].strip() for line in file}
```

This will remove other kinds of whitespace too, which is more than likely what you'd want.

If you just want to remove the last newline, use `.rstrip('\n')` instead of `.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can directly do this :

```
dct = dict([i.strip().split(':') for i in file.readlines()])
```