# how to remove "\n" from a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list that is read from a text file that outputs:

```
['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt\n']
```

I want to remove the \n from each element, but using .split() does not work on lists only strings (which is annoying as this is a list of strings).

How do I remove the \n from each element so I can get the following output:

```
['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt']
```

Comment: Iterate the list, then split the strings...

Comment: @Ellis, Why do you want to split the strings? Just `strip('\n')`.

Comment: @Austin I just used language as in the question. Also, I have not yet had my coffee :-)

Answer (score 2):

`old_list = [x.strip() for x in old_list]`

`old_list` refers to the list you want to remove the \n from.

Or if you want something more readable:

```
for x in range(len(old_list)):
    old_list[x] = old_list[x].strip()
```

Does the same thing, without list comprehension.

`strip()` method takes out all the whitespaces, including `\n`.

But if you are not ok with the idea of removing whitespaces from start and end, you can do:

`old_list = [x.replace("\n", "") for x in old_list]`

or

```
for x in range(len(old_list)):
    old_list[x] = old_list[x].replace("\n", "")
```

Comment: Or just `.strip()` - newline character is whitespace and `strip` with no arguments strips whitespace only. And only from the beginning and the end of the string.

Comment: As for your edit, nope. 1. Do not name own variable like a build-in one. 2. You don't save the result of the replace.

Comment: @h4z3: Bare `strip()` is a nice idea, only if OP is ok with removal of whitespaces (if any) from the ends.

Comment: I never understand why people say list comprehensions are less readable. They look less like “traditional” code than the for-loop but, in my experience of maintaining Python code, this makes them more rather than less readable.

Comment: It's just to make newbies' life easier. A newbie can understand the code better with traditional for loops. I think they are at least a bit more readable than list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[i.strip() for i in lines]
```

in case you don't mind to lost the spaces and tabs at the beginning and at the end of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Give this code a try:

```py
lst = ['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt\n']

for n, element in enumerate(lst):
    element = element.replace('\n', '')
    lst[n] = element

print(lst)
```

Comment: You don't need to check `if '\n' in element:`.

Comment: True, and also learned about the .strip() function with this post. 
Thanks for noticed that :)

Answer (score 0):

do a strip but keep in mind that the result is not modifying the original list, so you will need to reasign it if required:

```
a = ['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt\n']
a = [path.strip() for path in a]
print a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole file and split lines using str.splitlines:

temp = file.read().splitlines()

if you still have problems go to this question where I got the answer from

[How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)
answered Sep 8 '12 at 11:57 [Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510937/bakuriu)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve your result.

> **Method 1:** using *split()* method

```
l = ['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt\n']
result = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in l]

print(result) # ['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt']
```

> **Method 2:** using *strip()* method that removes leading and trailing whitespace

```
 l = ['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt\n']
result = [i.strip() for i in l]

print(result) # ['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt']
```

> **Method 3:** using *rstrip()* method that removes trailing whitespace

```
l = ['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt\n']
result = [i.rstrip() for i in l]

print(result) # ['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt']
```

> **Method 4:** using the method *replace*

```
l = ['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt\n', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt\n']

result = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in l]

print(result) # ['/Users/myname/Documents/test1.txt', '/Users/myname/Documents/test2.txt', '/Users/myname/Documents/test3.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it with lambda:

```
cleannewline = lambda somelist : map(lambda element: element.strip(), somelist)
```

Then you can just call it as:

```
cleannewline(yourlist)
```