# Unwanted '\n' removed when writing to txt line

Tags: python

So I have this text file:

```
Hoi

Total: 5700
-
-
```

And this code to change the Total: value:

```
with open("TEST.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
string = (lines[2])
stringNub = string.replace("Total: ","")

num = 300
sum = int(stringNub) + int(num)

with open('TEST.txt','r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()
    filedata = filedata.replace(stringNub, str(sum))
with open('TEST.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

This works but the result is minus one Enter '\n'.

```
Hoi

Total: 6000-
-
```

How do I keep it from removing this enter ?

Comment: This would be really obvious if you printed out what `stringNub` is. :) Try `print(repr(stringNub))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at this line `filedata = filedata.replace(stringNub, str(sum))` your variable `stringNub` containes the full line with the `\n` at the end, by replacing with `str(sum)` you are also removing the `\n`, to fix you could do :

```
with open('TEST.txt','r') as file:
    filedata = file.read()
    filedata = filedata.replace(stringNub, str(sum) + '\n')
```

or you could difine `stringNub` without  `\n` using `str.strip` and keep the rest of your code without changes:

```
stringNub = string.strip().replace("Total: ","")
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and solutions  :)

I would like to use the strip(), but I'm getting: ‘no attribute 'srip'.

Comment: @myosis it is actually 'strip', I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you convert `stringNub` into an int, the `\n` gets removed, the solution is simply add `\n` again when you want to write. Change the following line:

```
filedata = filedata.replace(stringNub, str(sum))
```

to this:

```
filedata = filedata.replace(stringNub, str(sum) + '\n')
```

Comment: Ah I figured it would be something like that, it did the trick alright. Thank you.