# How to turn a text file into a list and use index on the list

Tags: python

is it possible to find the position of a word in a text file?

The text file looks like this

Cat

Dog

Wolf

i tried using
`print(file.readlines.index("word"))`
but sadly it doesn't work

Comment: `print(file.readlines().index("word"))` might work better (your code isn't *calling* `readlines()`)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings in the list returned by the `readlines` method each end with a newline character, so you should strip the strings of the trailing newlines before matching them with the `index` method:

```
print([line.rstrip('\n') for line in file.readlines()].index('word'))
```

Since all you're looking for is the index of the first matching word, you can also improve the time and memory efficiency by using a generator expression instead:

```
print(next(i for i, line in enumerate(file) if line.rstrip('\n') == word))
```

Comment: `with open("username.txt") as f:
    print(f.readlines())
    print([line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines()].index('jeez123'))`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/log in and out/testing file.py", line 3, in <module>
    print([line.rstrip('\n') for line in f.readlines()].index('jeez123'))
ValueError: 'jeez123' is not in list
['\n', 'nono\n', 'jeez123\n']`

Comment: sorry for the messy comment i'm new to coding and also new to overflow. sorry for any confusion.

Comment: You should remove `print(f.readlines())` since it reads the file content and moves the file pointer to the end of the file so that the next cannot read the content anymore.

Comment: See demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/FuzzyWhimsicalEfficiency#main.py

Answer (score 0):

The issue here that `readlines()` reads new line symbol `\n` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines).

Here's an example:

```
In [12]: cat animals.txt                                                                                                
Cat
Dog
Wolf

In [13]: with open('animals.txt') as f: 
    ...:     print(f.readlines()) 
    ...:                                                                                                                
['Cat\n', 'Dog\n', 'Wolf\n']

In [14]: with open('animals.txt') as f: 
    ...:     print(f.read().splitlines()) 
    ...:                                                                                                                
['Cat', 'Dog', 'Wolf']

In [15]: with open('animals.txt') as f: 
    ...:     print(f.read().splitlines().index('Dog')) 
    ...:                                                                                                                
1
```