# How to add \n after every line in a txt file python

Tags: python

```
import requests
import time

req = requests.session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
a = open("codes.txt", "r").readlines()
param={
      "ID":a
}

source = req.post("http://www.example.com/api/", data=param, headers=headers)
if "valid" in source.text:
    print(source.text)
else:
     print(source.text)
```

So i have a file called codes.txt and i have some id's in the file.

```
1234
12345
12346
```

And after that i send a request to verify if the id is valid or not.

So when im checking and adding multiple ids in that txt file  it becomes 1 id 123412345123456

How i can add a \n to every line and make a request for every id.

Comment: "So when im checking and adding multiple ids in that txt file it becomes 1 id 123412345123456"

Can you please share how you are generating the text file?

Comment: It is not generated i just add to the txt files the ids.

Comment: Where do you see the id gets concatenated? Where does it become 123412345123456? You question is not clear.

Comment: There are a few things that seem off with your code, could you please clarify what each step does? For example `a` is a list, because `readlines()` returns a list, and so `param.ID` is also a list, which I'm guessing is wrong. What exactly should be going on here? :D

Comment: a = open("codes.txt", "r").readlines() 
opens the txt file   
param={
      "ID":a // The paramater is ID and 'a' is the txt file. so it's geting the values from the txt file. so in the request will be ID=1234
}
I just want to make 1 request/id in the txt file the id's are 1234 \n 12345 ..... but when im trying with multiple ids it is just checking for 1 or just adding them all together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop or iterate over the lines in the file. Here is how the modified version will look like:

```
import requests
import time

req = requests.session()
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
file_lines = open("codes.txt", "r").readlines()
for line in file_lines:
    param={
        "ID":line
    }

    source = req.post("http://www.example.com/api/", data=param, headers=headers)
    if "valid" in source.text:
        print(source.text)
    else:
        print(source.text)
```

Since each line is a entry that needs to be checked, you need to repeat the request with different parameter each time.

Comment: That not gonna help me at all, because im gonna have a lot of ids and add them manually is not gonna work out. i want to import the lines from the txt file into the id param.

Comment: @Zeko U dont need to manually do that. The code does that iteration for you. Try out my code in place of yours with one id per line in codes.txt.

Comment: My bad it's working how i wanted, i forgot to add the space after that and i thought something is wrong.thanks for helping appreciate your time <3

Comment: Also now for some reasons if use this only the last item will be checked corectly... and all the items will become false only the last one who doesn't have \n. So the items what has n\ at the end it gets false for some reasons..

Comment: It looks like the response is affected if there is a \n in the request. {'ID': '669615\n'} it return false if i have multiple values in the txt file only when {'ID': '669615'} without the \n is working fine. do you have any ideea if this can be fixed?

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that. Use `"ID":line.replace('\n','')`. That will remove any \n in the ID param

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines This might help you for further refernce