# How to create a text file for Selenium/Python to read with out extra character problems

Tags: python, selenium

I'm able to make the xpath find work in all ways except reading in customers from a text file.  I'm 98% sure it's a hidden character problem in the text file.   What's the easiest way to take a column of names in an Excel file and save it as a file that can be read with this bit of code?

```
customerlist = open("customerlist.txt", "r")

customers = customerlist.readlines()

for customer in customers:
   
   datarow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+customer+"')]")
```

Comment: maybe this will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines

Answer (score 1):

Inserting this as the first item in the for loop did the trick

customer = customer.rstrip("\n")