# How to convert line in file to string without newline?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, file, string-concatenation

I'm using Python 3 to loop through lines of a .txt file that contains strings. These strings will be used in a curl command. However, it is only working correctly for the last line of the file. I believe the other lines end with newlines, which throws the string off:

```
url = https://
with open(file) as f:
   for line in f:
       str = (url + line)
       print(str)
```

This will return:

```
https://
endpoint1
https://
endpoint2
https://endpoint3
```

How can I resolve all strings to concatonate like the last line?

I've looked at a couple of answers like [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines), but this answer converts all content in the file to one line.

Comment: I often use `for line in (line.rstrip() for line in f): ...` which uses a generator expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.strip`

**Ex:**

```
url = https://
with open(file) as f:
   for line in f:
       s = (url + line.strip())
       print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the strings end with newlines you can call `.strip()` to remove them. i.e:

```
url = https://
with open(file) as f:
   for line in f:
       str = (url + line.strip())
       print(str)
```

Comment: Thanks you, I went with .strip

Answer (score 1):

I think str.strip() will solve your problem