# Python how to convert a newline character to int()

Tags: python

I have several lists that I want to save in a `.txt` file, all on a new line. So, I have

```
list1 = [12, 32, 233]
list2 = [345, 823, 209]
```

and so on...
So I do

```
with open("textfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(list1))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(list2))
```

But when I try to read the file, as `int()`, I get an error saying: `invalid literal for int() with base 10` because the program thinks the `\n` is a character too and cannot convert it to `int()` How can I solve this issue?
Reading line:

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    actualList1 = int(data[0])
    actualList2 = int(data[1])
```

Comment: Please include the code that you are using to read the file. It should include the line creating issue and other relevant lines

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Comment: he doesnt need to reproduce a sample of the text file since he shows the code that generates it

Comment: Storing the representation of a list isn't the best of ideas if you want to read it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take it apart and store it delimited with spaces and then put it back together when reading it like so:

```
list1 = [12, 32, 233]
list2 = [345, 823, 209]

with open("textfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for lst in [list1,list2]:
        f.write(" ".join([str(i) for i in lst]) + "\n")

with open("textfile.txt", "r") as data:
    data = [i.strip() for i in data.readlines()]
    x = [[int(num) for num in i.split()] for i in data]

print(x)
```

```
[[12, 32, 233], [345, 823, 209]]
```

So what's going on?

well let's break it down into 2 steps; **storing the values** and **retrieving the values**

**part 1**

```
with open("textfile.txt", "w") as f:
    for lst in [list1,list2]:
        f.write(" ".join([str(i) for i in lst]) + "\n")
```

all this does is store the list separated by spaces

Using the `join` function we can easily accomplish this with one workaround; since the values stored inside the list are integers they must be strings when used with this function. Hence the use of the following list comprehension: `[str(i) for i in lst]`!

With that string, we can finally add a newline character to make sure we don't have one line of everything combined!

---

**part 2**

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as data:
    data = [i.strip() for i in data.readlines()]
    x = [[int(num) for num in i.split()] for i in data]
```

This is a little bit more complicated, in essence, this creates a list of the lines of the text file, and then strips them of newline characters.

From this, we `split` each line by spaces, and then cast each string to an integer value inside our newly created list.

Comment: It's better to avoid the use of `eval` due to its unsafe nature

Comment: its only unsafe if he is letting other users input to it, not if he's storing the code himself...

Comment: @Ironkey, funny thing, the worst data loss event I've been present for was a case where folks used that same reasoning to justify sloppy practices (and then a buffer overflow in a program writing data files caused garbage to be injected into filenames, which are what were being unsafely processed).

Comment: Anyhow, why would you use `eval` when you could instead use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) and get the same ability to parse Python literal data, but _not_ need to worry about there being code mixed into it?

Comment: Thanks for the eval answer! And as.literal_eval. But what does .strip() do?

Comment: `strip` just removes newline characters among other things, that way its not trying to interpret `"223\n"` as an int!

Comment: Why don't you just use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json)? Trying to parse python literals from files is a mug's game...

Comment: though text file parsing is still some good practice for beginners, he's right you could easily just store your lists there using methods like `json.dump`

Comment: @Ironkey Text file parsing is a good skill to learn, but learing which tool is right for the job will be much more valuable in the long run. This is especially true when it comes to `eval`, which is hardly ever the right tool for anything, and carries serious risks for newbies. Please don't ever suggest it when there are better and safer alternatives available.

Comment: edited to match then, ill add an explanation shortly

Answer (score 1):

```py
list1 = [12, 32, 233]
list2 = [345, 823, 2209]

with open("textfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(list1))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(list2))

with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()# since every line but the last ends with a '\n' I rather read than split to lines 
data = data.splitlines()
#you list is a string now so I split it like one
actualList1 = [int(x) for x in data[0][1:-1].split(',')]# split from 1 to -1 will remove parenthesize, after I split by ',' because its seperates the values
actualList2 = [int(x) for x in data[1][1:-1].split(',')]

print(actualList1)
print(actualList2)
```

Output:

```py
[12, 32, 233]
[345, 823, 2209]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note how the conversion issue is due also to `'['` and `']'` characters.

What you need is to strip all these characters (including also `'\n'`)  and then to split these numeric strings into a list. Finally you just have to convert them to `int`.

In this example we know that the file has at least two rows (this code is similar to yours):

```
list1 = [12, 32, 233]
list2 = [345, 823, 209]

with open("textfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(list1))
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(list2))


with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    actualList1 = [int(v) for v in data[0].strip("[]\n").split(",")]
    actualList2 = [int(v) for v in data[1].strip("[]\n").split(",")]
    print(actualList1)
    print(actualList2)
```

Output:

```
[12, 32, 233]
[345, 823, 209]
```

The previous snipped applied the fix to your code, but take a look to this solution, which works also with a variable number of rows (besides it is more elegant):

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for d in data:
        actualListRow = [int(v) for v in d.strip("[]\n").split(",")]
        print(actualListRow)
```