# Why is some output of the print function 2 lines and others 1?

Tags: python, discord

Im trying to make a script for Discord with python. But I have a weird thing with it. When I run this:

```
x = 1


def main():
    try:
        global x
        NitroCode = open("NitroCode.txt")
        Codes = NitroCode.readlines()
        
        #Url
        url = ("https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/" + Codes[x] + "?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true")
        print(url)
        
        x += 1
        main()
        
    except IndexError:
      print('Done Checking')
      exit()

main()
```

I get this output

```
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/b
?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/c
?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/d
?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/e
?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/f
?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/g
?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/h
?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/i
?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/j
?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true
https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/k?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true
Done Checking
```

Why is the last link is printed on a single line and others on two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Comment: start at x = 0 if you want to include all items in Codes[x]

Answer (score 2):

This is because `.readlines()` will include the new line (`\n`) character at the end of each line in the file. Notice how only the last URL worked as you expected? This is because the last line of the file did not end in a new line character (Enter) `\n`

This [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines) discusses a suitable alternative.

`codes = NitroCode.read().splitlines()`

Additionally, I recommend you use `with open("NitroCode.txt") as nitro_codes:` instead of `NitroCode = open("NitroCode.txt")` so that the file will be closed for you automatically upon exit/error.

Comment: I addition to the above stated i would use a for loop to iterate over the list of links.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `Codes[x]` contains a newline character for all values of `x` except the last one.

To remove any newline characters at the end you can do `Codes[x].rstrip('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `Codes[x]` is read from file with `\n` new line character in the end, so if you want to prevent that you should **strip** your `Codes[x]` value before concatenate:

```
"https://discordapp.com/api/v6/entitlements/gift-codes/" + Codes[x].strip() + "?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true"
```