# when reading a line from a text file in python with one word per line then printing the line with text after its adding another line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open("data.txt",'r') as f:
    player1 = f.readline()
    player2 = f.readline()

print (player1+" you are blue")
print (player2+" you are red")
```

my text file is

```
sam
jim
```

both are on a seperate line

currently it is outputing as

```
sam
 you are blue
jim
 you are red
```

I want it to output

```
sam you are blue
jim you are red
```

I have had a look around but can't seem to find an answer
I have also tried a .split and do a word count but I couldnt get it working

Comment: You'll find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines). The problem is when you read the line "sam", it is actually read as "sam\n" where "\n" indicates a new line. You need to `strip` the new line off of the text so it just reads "sam".

Answer (score 0):

you need to use strip to remove the trailing new line

```
with open ("data.txt",'r') as file:
    player1 = file.readline()
    player2 = file.readline()
    
print(player1.strip() + " you are blue" )
print(player2.strip() + " you are red")
```

Comment: thankyou the .strip() worked for me I didnt know about it I had to change where I put it in my code as I didnt put all 400lines of my code in it as it was just that bit that I coundnt do