# supress /n at the end of the txt file

Tags: python, text, txt

I have the following code:

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    print("x "+ data[1] + "y")
```

`data[1]` is the string from txt file. The result that I get:

```
>>> x 10
>>> y
```

but I would like "y" to be in the same line with "x 10". Is it possible to do in Python?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *"Is it possible to do in Python?"* - Yes.

Comment: Please look at indexing `data[1][:-1]` where last endline character can be removed easily

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to strip '\n' from data[1].

You can find it at this link.
[How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace either

```
>>>test = "the\n line"

>>>print(test)
the
 line

>>>print(test.replace("\n",""))
the line
```

Answer (score 0):

And note that `data[1] is the string from the txt file` is not accurate.  data[1] is the second line from the file.

```
    data = [line.rstrip() for line in f.readlines()]
```