# Get result in one line loop

Tags: python, string, loops, format

My output:

```
I have CMShehbaz
CMShehbaz
```

Expected:

```
I have CMShehbaz CMShehbaz
```

I am trying get result in one line. I tried with `end=""`, concat `+`, but did not
work. I want result in one line.

```
lines = []
with open('user.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

count = 0
for line in lines:
    count += 1
    print("I have {}  {}".format(line,line) )
    print(f'line {count}: {line}')
```

Comment: Before the print, try `line = line.strip()`. It removes whitespace on the ends.

Comment: readlines() read the linefeed too, returned array is [["CMShehbaz\n"], you need to use line.strip().

Comment: Please add a small sample of what's in `user.txt` to your question.

Comment: @usman has my updated answer helped you at all? If so it would be nice to have it marked as  answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you have a counter in there if all you want is a single string, but this will do that job.

user.txt

```
CMShehbaz1
CMShehbaz2
CMShehbaz3
```

python file

```py
with open('user.txt') as f:
    foo = "I have "
    bar = " ".join(line.strip() for line in f)
    print(foo+bar)

# Or you can do

    foo = " ".join(line.strip() for line in f)
    print(f"I have {foo}")
```

Gives you the output:

```
I have CMShehbaz1 CMShehbaz2 CMShehbaz3
```

If you want to know how many names are in foo then you can do

```py
    print(len(foo.split(' ')))  # this will give you 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that "user.txt" is a list of usernames each on a new line.

so in your code *line* will look something like "USER\n"

You can strip off the "\n" character of use some of the solutions posted previously: [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330522/how-to-read-a-file-without-newlines)