# Combine variable text in iterating over a sequence from file in python ('for' loop) without new line between that

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write a little more clearly.
Here, I want each line to stick together twice. normally from

```
a = "Hello"
b = "World"
print(a + b)
```

out >

```
"Hello world"
```

It can be used, but the problem I found is as follows:
My intention is to paste each line into its own repetition without the extra line.

```
with open('domains.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        test_var = line+line
        print(test_var)
```

out:

```
"string
string
string2
string2
string3
string3"
```

so I want this output **(without new line between that)**:

```
"string string
string2 string2
string3 string3"
```

Comment: you want every 2 items concat and then add new line ?

Comment: Please don't lie about your outputs. Actually run the codes and show the real outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print()` has an optional `end` parameter which defaults to `\n`, the newline character. If you specify `print(Test_var, end='')`, you'll be able to print without any space between the outputs. Then, you can manually `print('\n')` to control where your new lines end up!

That being said, I think you're also fighting a separate issue where the file is being read in with the newline characters still appended to the end of the line. Check out [How to read a file without newlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12330522/19882427) for advice on removing newline characters from the lines you're reading.